# Is the quotient of the two left sides equal to the quotient of the two right sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Math problem**

The problem is if two equations that neither left side equals zero, would the quotients of the two left sides be equal to the quotient of the two right sides? If *a = b* and *c = d*, neither *a* nor *c* is 0, then *a/c = b/d*.

My solution
If the sum of both equations is equal, meaning if a = b and c = d, then a/c = b/d.

**Textbook solution**

Because we can take the reciprocals of both sides of an equation to get another equation, we have 1/c = 1/d. We can then multiply this equation by a = b to get a/c = b/d. Therefore, the quotient of the left sides of two equations equals the quotient of the right sides of the equations(as long as we aren't dividing by 0!)

**My issue**

I am confused as to why the textbook solution is using a "less simple" way of using the reciprocals of the denominators and then multiplying them by *a* and *b*. Isn't my way more simple and more obvious/efficient? I can't foresee my way being a problem in later advanced math concepts. But, please prove my assumption wrong because I still believe the textbook knows better than me, I just don't understand the "why" to their solution.

Comment: The sum of the two equations is $a+c=b+d$. Not what you need to conclude. Your solution is like saying "Since toast is bread, then this salad is bread."

Answer (score 1):

Like Arturo Magidin said, your use of the word "sum" is problematic, but I think that's somewhat besides the point. Or rather, I suspect that you didn't really mean the sum (i.e. the numerical addition of something)?

To me, it sounds like your textbook is working under some set of rules that it allows itself to use, things like
$$
a=b\land c=d \implies a+c=b+d,
$$
and so on. So it wants to prove the statement using previously agreed upon statements, in particular taking the product of two equalities is considered fair game by them.

What I think is more natural is to go a more direct/general way like you. We can expand it into two steps to be very clear:
$$
\frac ac = \frac bc = \frac bd.
$$
First we used $a=b$, and then we used $c=d$. I would probably call this the principle of substitution if I wanted to be fancy. I.e., if $a$ and $b$ are the same, then you can use them interchangeably in *any* kind of expression - no need to consider the specific scenario at all. Of course, to even write $\frac ac$ from the beginning, we needed $c\ne 0$ as an assumption.

Bottom line could be that you might be totally correct, but it depends on what exactly is going on in your head.